# How to get Coarse-grained Part of Speech Tags?

Tags: parsing, nlp, classification, feature-extraction, part-of-speech

I have a data set which is annotated by Collins parser. Right now, I am keeping the POS of each word in the data set as a feature. The problem is that I don't need fine-grained POS. So, I have combined some of the tags. For example, I assume all VBD,VBP,VBZ,VBG under the category of "Verb". And for nouns, I assume NNP and NNS as "Noun" category.

So, here is the list of POS tags that I have after doing all combinations:

> VB, NN, TO, JJ, IN, EX, RB, WP, PRP, MD, UH, WRB, WDT, RP, CD, POS, DT, PRP$, WP$, CC, RBR

Now, my question is where can I find a list of coarse-grained POS tags? Is there any standard coarse-grained POS tag list?

In my system, If I don't combine other POS tags, I can get better results. I am wondering if I am allowed to keep my current list? Or should I combine them as well?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Petrov's universal tag set. The universal tag set is 12 in number and increases the POS tagging efficiency drastically. You can refer [Universal POS tagset](http://www.petrovi.de/data/lrec.pdf) You can also download the code and the mappings for few taggers at [POS mapping](http://code.google.com/p/universal-pos-tags/downloads/list)